# ListView Footer causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-listview, indexoutofboundsexception, baseadapter

I've a `ListView` with a footer (simple `LinearLayout` with a `TextView` and a `ImageView`), and a `BaseAdapter` with 2 `View` types:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

My problem is when I scroll the list to the bottom and reach the footer because this exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
            at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6444)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4993)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4197)
...
```

If I increment my `getViewTypeCount()` to 3 everything works fine.
This is the first time I'm experiencing this error, in other projects I've BaseAdapters with more ViewTypes and with footers and headers and it works fine without the "increment hack".

**EDIT:** **BaseAdapter** code:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItemsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItemsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mItemsList.get(position).getValue().equals(mContext.getString(R.string.stub))) {
            return STUB;
        }
        return ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == ITEM) {
            return itemView(position, convertView);
        }
        return stubView(convertView);
    }
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: can you post your full adapter class here.

Comment: @Sajal question updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getViewTypeCount()` is used to instantiate an array of `convertView`s, indexed by the returned value of `getItemViewType()`, and like every array, it is `0-based`. For this reason your `getItemViewType()` can't return a value grater than or equal to the value of `getViewTypeCount()`. The only values possible with `getViewTypeCount() == 2` are `0` and `1`

Answer (score 1):

I've got it! I had:

```
private static final int ITEM = 1;
private static final int STUB = 2;
```

instead of

```
private static final int ITEM = 0;
private static final int STUB = 1;
```

Thanks @Blackbelt your answer reminded me to check out my type "index" values.